# When does rep get updated on Meta towards the main?

Tags: support, reputation

We all know that the rep on meta is associated with the main's own. Sometimes, we would see our rep how it looked like previously in the meta. So when **DOES** the meta rep get updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Help Center article [What is "meta"? How does it work?](/help/whats-meta):

> your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Arqade (**synchronized hourly**), though you earn separate badges.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: There is also still a [relevant bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317269/201625) revolving around meta reputation (display only)